# backbone data view not showing

Tags: backbone.js

I have been having a few issue with backbone so decided to do a very simple tutorial.

After getting this working I tried to simplify it but now cannot get it working.

I think the problem is around returning the view to the screen..

here is the code

```
var Theater = {
Models: {},
Collections: {},
Views: {},
Templates:{}
}

Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({})

Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: Theater.Models.Movie,
url: "scripts/data/movies.json",
initialize: function(){
    console.log("Movies initialize")
}
});

Theater.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Movie").html())

Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
el: $("#mainContainer"),
template: Theater.Templates.movies,
//collection: new Theater.Collections.Movies(), //Not needed

initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, "render");
    this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
},

render: function () {
    $(this.el).append(this.template(this.collection.toJSON())) ;
}

})


Theater.Router = Backbone.Router.extend({
routes: {
    "": "defaultRoute" 
},

defaultRoute: function () {
    Theater.movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies()
    new Theater.Views.Movies({ collection: Theater.movies }); 
    Theater.movies.fetch();
}
})

var appRouter = new Theater.Router();
Backbone.history.start();
```

and here is the very basic html

```
   <div id="mainContainer"></div>

<script type="text/template" id="tmplt-Movie">

    <div><%=name %> </div>

</script>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this.collection.toJSON())` converts `collection` into a `json`, so trying to access `name` on it in the template won't give you anything.

You can write your `render` method like this:

```
render : function() {
  var _view = this;
  this.collection.each(function(model) {
    $(_view.el).append(_view.template(model.toJSON())); // assuming model has 'name' attribute which is accessed in the template code
  });
}
```

This should work.

Comment: thanks but this just gives an error which says _view.$el is undefined

Comment: oh, ok then try $(_view.el) instead of _view.$el. Seems you're using older version of backbone.

Comment: ok yeah that works.. was something I was trialling.. thanks for the help.. _view.el worked also :)

Comment: @Dan, why do you use var _view = this; ? Just curious

Comment: I am guessing because you are in a loop if you just used this you would not have the correct view.. it would change each loop..

Comment: Hi thearchitect, inside the `collection.each` its a function, so inside function if we use `this` it won't refer to the view, it will refer to the `function` instead, hence we store the reference of `this` in `_view` and use it in the callback. Hope it clears your doubts.

Comment: @Cyclone I have used this logic in my app but now I get a page which doesnt show anything.. if you get a chance could you have a look at this? thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13743361/changing-a-page-in-jqm-after-a-fetch-view-not-displaying-backbone

Answer (score 0):

You have an incorrect template

```
template: Theater.Templates.movies,
```

In the render function use

```
var template = _.template( $("#tmplt-Movie").html(), this.collection.toJSON() );
this.$el.html( template );
```

Try that. If it fails. Try some console to log to check that fetch is being called, the collection is being populated and that render is being called. If render is being called then it just a matter of correcting a small mistake that will probably be related to dom selection.

Comment: what do you mean an incorrect template? I dont understand?


also that didnt work... gives a data underscore error..

Comment: remove the line template: Theater.Templates.movies,

Check out http://backbonetutorials.com/what-is-a-view/ if you're just getting started

Comment: I did take it out. the problem is that I get an error saying Name is undefined and that is correct.. I think i am missing something from the view

Comment: If it says name is undefined that the data is not being passed correclty. I think you can combine with the other answer since it includes the looping through the collection

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to provide a collection to the template, and that the template should loop through the collection and present the values. You can provide a collection to a template, but that’s probably not the best way.

The primary problem seems that you are using a colleciton where you should be using an model. In the render function you are passing a collection to the template. The template should take Models Json.

This is where sub views can be used. So you would want a primary view that takes a collection and that primary view will call a subview that will accept a model.

I did provide an example on jsFiddle.net. It’s somewhat of an hack. Instead of passing a colleciton into the template, I passed an individual item from the collection. This will only render 1 model. Since Routing can be confusing, I went ahead and removed it.
[Example on jsFiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/BarDev/gdQMr/5/).  I sometime have problems with IE and jsFiddle.net.  I recommend using the Chrome Browser.

```
this.$el.append(this.template(this.collection.at(0).toJSON()));
```

Just this month I did started creating more simple tutorials on Backbone.js. This list of tutorial is located at the bottom of this page:
[More Simple Backbone.js Examples](http://bardevblog.wordpress.com/2012/12/04/re-learning-backbone-js/)

Hopefully soon, I will have the time create a simple tutorial on rendering colletion.

Here's the complete code

```
<div id="mainContainer"></div>
```

```
var Theater = {
    Models: {},
    Collections: {},
    Views: {},
    Templates: {}
};

Theater.Models.Movie = Backbone.Model.extend({});

Theater.Collections.Movies = Backbone.Collection.extend({
    model: Theater.Models.Movie,
    //url: "scripts/data/movies.json",
    initialize: function() {
        console.log("Movies initialize")
    }
});

Theater.Templates.movies = _.template($("#tmplt-Movie").html());

Theater.Views.Movies = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $("#mainContainer"),
    template: Theater.Templates.movies,
    //collection: new Theater.Collections.Movies(), //Not needed
    initialize: function() {
        _.bindAll(this, "render");
        this.collection.bind("reset", this.render, this);
    },
    render: function() {
        this.$el.append(this.template(this.collection.at(0).toJSON()));
    }
});


var movies = new Theater.Collections.Movies();

var movieView = new Theater.Views.Movies({ collection: movies });

var myMovies =
[{
    "Id": "BVwi1",
    "Name": "Bag It",
    "AverageRating": 4.6,
    "ReleaseYear": 2010,
    "Url": "http://www.netflix.com/Movie/Bag_It/70153545",
    "Rating": "NR"
},
{
    "Id": "BW1Ss",
    "Name": "Lost Boy: The Next Chapter",
    "AverageRating": 4.6,
    "ReleaseYear": 2009,
    "Url": "http://www.netflix.com/Movie/Lost_Boy_The_Next_Chapter/70171826",
    "Rating": "NR"
}];

movies.reset(myMovies);
```

I hope this help.